# How to specify characters using hexadecimal codes in `grep`?

Tags: shell, grep, character-encoding, unicode

I am using following command to grep character set range for hexadecimal code 0900 (instead of अ) to 097F (instead of व). How I can use hexadecimal code in place of अ and व?

```
bzcat archive.bz2 | grep -v '<[अ-व]*\s' | tr '[:punct:][:blank:][:digit:]' '\n' | uniq | grep -o '^[अ-व]*$' | sort -f | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -50000 | awk '{print "<w f=\""$1"\">"$2"</w>"}' > hindi.xml
```

I get the following output:

```
    <w f="399651">और</w>
    <w f="264423">एक</w>
    <w f="213707">पर</w>
    <w f="74728">कर</w>
    <w f="44281">तक</w>
    <w f="35125">कई</w>
    <w f="26628">द</w>
    <w f="23981">इन</w>
    <w f="22861">जब</w> 
    ...
```

I just want to use hexadecimal code instead of अ and व in the above command.

If using hexadecimal code is not at all possible , can I use unicode instead of hexadecimal code for character set ('अ-व') ?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Also `-v` inverts the match, from your question text it seems that is not what you want.

Comment: @Christian.K Sorry for the delay... I have edited the question , please take a look.

Comment: I am still waiting for an appropriate answer . :(

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Look at [grep: Find all lines that contain Japanese kanjis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65715/grep-find-all-lines-that-contain-japanese-kanjis).

Text is usually encoded in UTF-8; so you have to use the hex vales of the bytes used in UTF-8 encoding.

```
grep "["$'\xe0\xa4\x85'"-"$'\xe0\xa4\xb5'"]"
```

and

```
grep '[अ-व]'
```

are equivalent, and they perform a [character class / bracket expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) locale-based matching (that is, matching is dependent on the sorting rules of Devanagari script (that is, the matching is *NOT* "any char between \u0905 and \0935" but instead "anything sorting between Devanagari A and Devanagari VA"; there may be differences.

(`$'...'` is the "ANSI-C escape string" syntax for bash, ksh, and zsh. It is just an easier way to type the characters. You can also use the `\uXXXX` and `\UXXXXXXXX` escapes to directly ask for code points in bash and zsh.)

On the other hand, you have this (note -P):

```
grep -P "\xe0\xa4[\x85-\xb5]"
```

that will do a *binary* matching with those *byte* values.

Comment: Please explain the prefix `"["$'` and suffix `"]"`

Answer (score 7):

If shell escaping is enough you can use the `$'\xHH'` syntax like this:

```
grep -v "<["$'\x09\x00'"-"$'\x09\x7F'"]*\s"
```

Is that enough for your use case?

Comment: `echo 'अ-व' | hd` gives me `e0 a4 85 - e0 a4 b5`

Comment: Indeed the OP gave unicode values, not hexadecimal dumps in UTF-8 encoding :-/ Since `grep` is not linked with any lib, I guess it's not possible to have the range conversion be performed by grep :-/

Comment: Btw, `zsh` is able to interpret `"\u0900"` and `"\u097F"`, but the behavior will rely on the UTF-8 encoded range being continuous (probably it is).

Comment: No grep -v "<["$'\x09\x00'"-"$'\x09\x7F'"]*\s" gives following output 

<w f="16929">x</w>
<w f="10995">F</w>
<w f="2548">FF</w>
<w f="762">FFFFFF</w>
<w f="655">FFFF</w>
<w f="266">xx</w>
<w f="215">FFF</w>
<w f="117">xxx</w>
....
This is not expected. :(  , 
Can I use unicode instead of hexadecimal code or character set ('अ-व') ?

Answer (score 7):

The "hexadecimal" value `0x0900` you wrote is exactly the value of the UNICODE code point which is also in hexadecimal.

> hexadecimal code 0900 (instead of अ)

I believe that what you mean to say is the hexadecimal UNICODE code point: `U0905`.

The character at U-0900 is not the one you used: `अ`.
[That character is U0905](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0905/index.htm), part of [this Unicode page](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf), or listed at [this page](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F).

In `bash` (installed by default in Ubuntu), or directly with the program at: `/usr/bin/printf` (but not with `sh` printf), an Unicode character could be produced with:

```
$ printf '\u0905'
अ
$ /usr/bin/printf '\u0905'
अ
```

However, that character, which comes from a code point number could be represented by several byte streams depending of which code page is used.
It should be obvious that `\U0905` is `0x09 0x05` in UTF-16 (UCS-2, etc)
and `0x00 0x00 0x09 0x05` in UTF-32.
It may not be obvious but in utf-8 it is represented by `0xe0 0xa4 0x85`:

```
$ /usr/bin/printf '\u0905' | od -vAn -tx1
e0 a4 85
```

If the locale of your console is something similar to `en_US.UTF-8`.

And I am talking about the shell because it is the one that transforms a string into what the application receives. This:

```
grep "$(printf '\u0905')" file
```

makes grep "see" the character you need.
To understand the line above you may use echo:

```
$ echo grep "$(printf '\u0905')" file
grep अ file
```

Then, we can build a character range, as you request:

```
$ echo grep "$(printf '[\u0905-\u097f]')" file
grep [अ-ॿ] file
```

That answer your question:

> How I can use hexadecimal code in place of अ and व?

Comment: This is by far the best answer---it clearly addresses the issue of unicode points' representations in the shell  and shows how to go back and forth between them hex codes.

Answer (score 4):

we wanted to convert the non-ascii open double quote and close double quote to regular double quotes (").  Also the non-ascii single quote to regular single quote (').

to see them in the file (ubuntu bash shell):

```
$ grep -P "\x92" infile.txt  (single)
$ grep -P "\x93" infile.txt  (open double)
$ grep -P "\x94" infile.txt  (close double)
```

translate them:

```
$ /bin/sed "s/\x92/'/g" a.txt > b.txt
$ /bin/sed 's/\x93/"/g' b.txt > c.txt
$ /bin/sed 's/\x94/"/g' c.txt > d.txt
```

Comment: `-P` is short form of `--perl-regexp` option, which enables (among many things) `\xNN` syntax.