# grep: Find all lines that contain Japanese kanjis

Tags: grep, unicode

In a huge UTF-8 text file, I want to show all lines that contains Japanese [kanjis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji).
What `grep` (or other) expression does this?

If I am not mistaken, kanjis are the characters between `\u4e00` and `\u4dbf`.

I don't need to show [kanas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kana), but showing them too would not be a big problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is impossible (without using a huge table) to tell apart a japanese kanji from a Han ideograph not used in Japanese (eg, a chinese or korean variant).

If you just want to detect any Han ideograph in the basic range (\u4e00 to \u9fff)
then they are encoded in 3 bytes, the first byte is always between 0xe4 and 0xe9, the second and third bytes between 0x80 and 0xbf.

There are two difficulties here, first you have to tell grep you want to look after bytes and not characters; then you have to type the 0xe4, 0xe9, 0x80 and 0xbf bytes to put them in the regexp expression.

I discovered the -P switch does both; and the line you want is:

```
grep -P "[\xe4-\xe9][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]"
```

and if you want kana too:

```
grep -P "[\xe4-\xe9][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|\xe3[\x81-\x83][\x80-\xbf]"
```

Comment: That works great!

Answer (score 5):

According to the fifth table [here](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.unicode.shtml), kanji are the caracters between `\u4e00` and `\u9fff`

My implementation of `grep` doesn't seem to be able to handle unicode characters (that's GNU grep 2.14 on Archlinux), but we can still use `\x`. You can find the respective codes [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl) or use a tool like `hexedit` to get them.

For anything in our range of interest above `e9 be a5` returned "Invalid collation character" so this is what I've come up with:

```
grep "["$'\xe4\xb8\x80'"-"$'\xe9\xbe\xa5'"]" file.txt
```

Comment: +1 That works too, but Pablo was a bit faster...

Comment: That is equivalent to `grep "[一-龥]"`. the problem is it is locale-dependent, and uses collation rules; that is, only elements for which a sorting order is defined can be used in the range or matched. The `-P` switch just does binary matching, regardless of the locale. A locale-based approach will use a cultural definition of "character range", a binary-based approach will use an encoding value definition of "range". Particularly for alphabetic scripts the output is quite different. (here for Han ideographics it is roughly equivalent)