# Is there a way to grep a folder and show all lines containing non-ascii characters?

Tags: grep, search

Some code I am working with has a bunch of comments written in Japanese and I am working on translating them to English. Is there some way to "grep" for all lines containing Japanese characters or at least any non-ascii characters?

Comment: Does it have to be grep? perl has more extensive unicode support, I think e.g. `print if /\P{ASCII}/` or possibly `print if /\p{Hiragana}/`, `print if /\p{Katakana}/` etc. See for example [How Can I Run a Regex that Tests Text for Characters in a Particular Alphabet or Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334213)

Comment: @steeldriver: Perl is OK. But how do I run that search for every file in a directory, recursively? And is it going to print file names and line numbers like grep does? (You can put that as an answer, btw)

Comment: OK my perl-fu is not strong but I will try to put together an answer: in the meantime, I found this near-duplicate that you may find helpful [grep: Find all lines that contain Japanese kanjis](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65715/65304)

Comment: If the characters you're looking for are comprised of invalid byte-sequences in your current encoding, then you can probably just find them like: `grep -xv '.*' *` because the `.*` will only match a line head to tail if it is comprised entirely of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grepping for non-ASCII characters is easy: set a locale where only ASCII characters are valid, search for invalid characters.

```
LC_CTYPE=C grep '[^[:print:]]' myfile
```

If you want to search for Japanese characters, it's a bit more complicated. With grep, you'll need to make sure that your `LC_CTYPE` locale setting matches the encoding of the files. You'll also need to make sure that your `LC_COLLATE` setting is set to Japanese if you want to use a character range expression. For example, on Linux (I determined the first and last character that's considered Japanese by looking at the `LC_COLLATE` section `/usr/share/i18n/locales/ja_JP`):

```
LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.UTF-8 egrep '[｡-龥]' myfile
```

or if you want to stick to ASCII in your script

```
LC_CTYPE=ja_JP.UTF-8 LC_COLLATE=ja_JP.UTF-8 egrep $'[\uff61-\u9fa5]' myfile
```

This includes a few punctuation characters that are also used in English such as `ⓒ` and `×`.

Perl has built-in features to classify characters. You can use the [`\p` character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Unicode-Properties) to match characters based on [Unicode properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties). Pass the [command line switch `-CSD`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5b_number%2flist_%5d*) to tell Perl that everything is in Unicode with the UTF-8 encoding.

```
perl -CSD -ne 'print if /\p{Hiragana}|\p{Katakana}/' myfile
```

If your files aren't encoded in UTF-8, you'll have to call [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) explicitly to tell Perl about their encoding. That's too advanced a [perllocale](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html) usage for me. Alternatively you can [first recode the line into UTF-8](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193708).

Alternatively, in Perl, you can use numerical character ranges. For example, to search for characters in the Hiragana and Katakana Unicode blocks:

```
perl -CSD -ne 'print if /[\x{3040}-\x{30ff}]/' a
```

Comment: The `grep [^[:print:]]` version is also printing tab characters. Is there a way to avoid that? BTW you were right about the file encodings, turns out it was actually EUCJP

Comment: @hugomg Add a tab inside the outer brackets: `grep '[^[:print:]TAB]' myfile` or `grep '[^TAB[:print:]]' myfile` or `grep $'[^[:print:]\t]' myfile` or `grep $'[^\t[:print:]]' myfile` (with an actual tab character instead of TAB).

Comment: In [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/193686/32477) @janis suggests using `grep '[^[:print:][:space:]]'` to handle tab and space characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep '[^[:print:][:space:]]'
```

(Depending on your locale setting maybe you have to prepend it by `LANG=C`.)

Comment: This ends up with lots of false positives because its also printing lines with tabs ("\t") on them.

Comment: I changed the answer to ignore spaces and TABs as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using perl, it has more extensive Unicode support in the form of classes such as `{Katakana}` and `{Hiragana}` which I don't think are currently available in even in those versions of grep that provide some PCRE support. However it does appear to require explicit UTF-8 decoding e.g.

```
perl -MEncode -ne 'print if decode("UTF-8",$_) =~ /\p{Hiragana}/' somefile
```

To traverse directories like grep's -R, you could use the `find` command, something like

```
find -type f -exec perl -MEncode -ne 'print if decode("UTF-8",$_) =~ /\p{Hiragana}/' {} \;
```

or to mimic recursive grep's default `filename:match` labeled output format,

```
find -type f -exec perl -MEncode -lne 'printf "%s:%s\n",$ARGV,$_ if decode("UTF-8",$_) =~ /\p{Hiragana}/' {} \;
```

Comment: Sadly, none of these worked for me, maybe because the file is encoded in iso-8859-1 (though fiddling with LC_CTYPE and the parameter to decode didn't seem to help). I managed to find a solution to my problem in the thread you linked to though :)

Comment: @hugomg A file encoded in ISO 8859-1 cannot contain any Japanese characters. It's probably UTF-8, EUCJP or a JIS variant.

Answer (score 0):

My files were encoded in iso-8859-1 so anything that tried to read the input in my default locale (utf-8) would not recognize the Japanese characters. In the end I managed to solve my problem with the following command:

```
env LC_CTYPE=iso-8859-1  grep -nP '[\x80-\xff]' ./*
```

-P is to allow for the Perllike syntax for character ranges.
-n is for printing the line numbers next to the line names

`\x80` to `\xff` are the "non ascii" characters

Changing the LC_CTYPE environment variable to iso-8859-1 makes grep read my fields byte-by-byte and lets me detect any "extended ascii" bytes as possible Japanese characters. If I use the default system encoding of UTF-8 grep exits with an "invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in input" error.