# How do I grep for a range of unicode characters?

Tags: grep

How do I grep for a range of unicode characters?

I've seen an example for one character. [How to grep characters with their unicode value?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523327/how-to-grep-characters-with-their-unicode-value)

I'm interested in a method other than the shell substitution method

<s>because shell substitution seems to be a bit limited e.g. it doesn't seem to work for a non-graphical unicode characters like codepoint of \u80.</s>

I can get that method to work for a range, <s>but only to an extent, since it won't cover non-graphical characters like \u80 (unicode codepoint 80)</s>

```
$ echo grep [$'\u41'-$'\u45']
grep [A-E]

$ echo 4142434445|xxd -r -p
ABCDE

$ echo 4142434445|xxd -r -p | grep [$'\u41'-$'\u45']
ABCDE
```

<s>The $ method uses substitution at the shell level so won't work to e.g. look for characters from `\u0080-\uFFFF` or `\u0080` upwards, 'cos if the shell can't display a character, it won't work.</s>

ugrep is available through apt-get for debian, though not for the ubuntu version I have on the VPS I have. And I have to test it some more.

**NOTE**  Turns out the shell substitution method does work for control characters so would even work for a range of them or any unicode characters, as no doubt would ugrep. Initially when I tried shell substitution with grep, I was unknowingly feeding in wrong bytes. e.g. `echo 418042| xxd -r -p` displays `A▒B` so I thought great that worked, and I was trying to grep on that. So I was piping wrong data to grep.    80 is not utf-8 for \u80. An echo of high characters e.g. £ clearly shows it is outputting utf-8. `echo £ | xxd -p` shows `c2a30a` c2a3 is utf-8 for £.   When I fed in correct bytes it worked e.g. `c280` is \u80 and even  `echo $'\u80'` worked .   This page is good for showing utf-8 mappings to unicode codepoints. https://www.utf8-chartable.de/

While shell substitution does work, i'm glad I have an answer that does a method other than shell substitution, as having an alternative is good.

Comment: `egrep '[\u1600-\u16ff]'` would be sort of the obvious thing to try, but not sure if will work

Comment: "won't work to e.g. look for characters from \u0080-\uFFFF or \u0080 upwards, 'cos if the shell can't display a character, it won't work" -- hmm, what shell are you using? Seems to me Bash can interpret and print e.g. `$'\u00e4'` or `$'\u2667'`  just fine, giving `ä` and `♧`.

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks.. I think I had control characters in mind.

Comment: @ilkkachu More to the point, the shell does not display characters. This is left up to the terminal emulator and depends on the fonts available to the terminal.

Comment: @doneal24, yes, the shell isn't involved if we actually _display_ something. I think I was mostly thinking about the possibility that the shell might croak on having to just handle some characters, for whatever reason not related to actual displaying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In gnu-grep and similar you can use PCRE option `-P` and use
`\x{HHHH}` syntax

```
$ grep -o -P '[\x{0410}-\x{042F}]+' # same as: grep -o -P '[А-Я]+'
абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕ

=> АБВГДЕ
```

Answer (score 2):

I spoke to some perl experts. and got perl one liner equivalents of grepping for a range of unicode characters.

```
$ echo £
£
```

So there's this concept of an ordinal, which is a numeric representation of a character.   (I suppose regardless of whether something is an encoding or a codepoint. The word ordinal is useful to describe what follows \x which depending on options, could be an encoding , so stored bytes, or could be a unicode codepoint, bytes but not encoded for storing in / writing to memory)

It's in bytes/octets. Which can be represented in various bases.

`%v` is a format specifier of printf,

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%vx\n",A'
41

$ perl -e 'printf "%vx\n",4'
34
```

%vd would be 52 (decimal numeric representation of the character '4'. %vx is hex representation

UTF-8 encoding for £ is c2a3  https://www.utf8-chartable.de/

```
$ echo £ | xxd -p
c2a30a
```

When using \x with more than two digits, you have to use curly braces with it. \x{..}

```
$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[\x0A]/'
£

$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[\x{0080}-\x{FFFF}]/'
£
```

the -CIO converted the ordinal from a UTF-8 representation(c2a3), to a unicode codepoint representation(a3).  Hence when using -CIO with \x, then what follows \x should be a unicode codepoint representation

The one below matches it to anything \u0080 and upwards. Not stopping at \uFFFF. Just a regex thing there.

```
$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[^\x00-\x7f]/'
£
```

If you remove the -CIO then you'd be matching UTF-8 bytes, rather than unicode codepoint bytes. Because without the -CI, it's not converting/interpreting/decoding, the UTF-8 encoded bytes, to a unicode codepoint.

```
$ echo £ | perl -ne 'print if /\xc2/'
£

$ echo £ | perl -ne 'print if /\xa3/'
£
```

So in summary

```
$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[\x{0080}-\x{FFFF}]/'
£

$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[^\x00-\x7f]/'
£

$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[^\x{00}-\{x7f}]/'
£

$ echo £ | perl -CIO -ne 'print if /[^\x{0000}-\{x007f}]/'
£
```

The `perl -CIO` is documented by  `perldoc perlrun`

```
 -C [*number/list*]
         The -C flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features.

...
             I     1   STDIN is assumed to be in UTF-8
             O     2   STDOUT will be in UTF-8
```

and perldoc perlunicode and perldoc perlre mention \x{...}

Answer (score 2):

Setting `LC_COLLATE` to `C` on GNU systems at least should guarantee the order be based on the Unicode code point in locales where the charmap is multibyte (such as UTF-8, GB18030), and on the byte value other wise (which in locales using ASCII or ISO-8859-1 should also match the unicode code point order).

So:

```
LC_COLLATE=C grep $'[\u1111-\uaaaa]'
```

Should find line that contain at least one character whose unicode code point is between U+1111 and U+AAAA (encoded as per the locale's charmap as indicated by the `LC_CTYPE` setting). That assumes `$LC_ALL` is not otherwise set (as it would take precedence over `$LC_COLLATE`).

I would advise avoiding the range to span the invalid U+D800 - U+DFFF range. Codepoints in that range are reserved for UTF-16 encoding and are not for valid characters, and have otherwise been used to encode invalid characters with some tools. Use characters within the U+0001 and U+D7FF and U+E000 and U+10FFFF.

You'll also want to make sure the bounds of your range correspond to valid characters in your locale. The behaviour for `$'\uxxxx'`, where U+xxxx is not a character in the locale's charset varies between shells that support that `$'\u...'` operator. In some shells (including ksh93 where `$'...'` comes from `$'\u...'` being from zsh), `$'\u...'` only works in locales that use UTF-8 as the charmap (see output of `locale charmap`).